# Exception caught by image resource service (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI) when am inserting the image from file picker

Tags: flutter, image, dart, picker

[image]please anyone can help how to solve this issue

when am inserting an image from gallery it show this error

```
 if (image == null) return;

                  final location = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  final name = path.basename(image.path);
                  final imageFile = File('${location.path}/$name');
                  final newImage =
                      await File(image.path).copy(imageFile.path);
                  setState(
                      () => user = user.copy(imagePath: newImage.path));
                },
                child: Image.network(user.image),
              ))),
      Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 330,
                height: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'Update',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
```

i also used print method but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
child: Image.network(user.image),
```

do:

```
child: Image.file(imageFile),
```

Comment: and bare in mine to include checking if you want to show the current profile photo (on the server). a profile photo from the server needs to use the "Image.network" widget and the image you fetch from the gallery needs to use Image.file widget.